# Regex replace multiple spaces unless preceded by . or followed by digit

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to construct a regex replace function that will change all instances of multiple spaces to a single space, unless it is two spaces preceded by a period (.), or multiple spaces followed by a digit ([0-9]).

**Example:**

```
//original string
"The dog  jumped  over the fence.   So did the cat    900kg"

//should be
"The dog jumped over the fence.  So did the cat    900kg"
```

**What I have so far:**

```
string.replace(/(?<!\.)  +(?=[^0-9])/g,' ');
```

This only issue is that this expression only leaves 2 spaces before the digit instead of leaving them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<!\.)\s\s+(?!\d|\s)`

Not a `.`, one `space`, one or more additional `spaces` followed by *not* a `number` or another `space`.

https://regex101.com/r/sfUfRI/1/